# Issue with python code, why does variable getting overridden?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a RGB image of size (227,227,3) and one grayscale image of size (227,227). Now I want to replace RGB planes of the image by the grayscale image. Below I have the code. Now, the issue with code is `imgNew` is getting overridden even though I am not changing it's value and getting wrong images for `imgR,imgG,imgB`.

```
#this is my rgb image 
imgNew = imresize(img[480 / 2 - 160 + r[l, 0]:480 / 2 + 160  + r[l, 0], 640 / 2 - 160 + r[m, 1]:640 / 2 + 160  + r[m, 1], :],(227,227))
# this is grascale 
imgDNew = imresize(imgx[480 / 2 - 160 + r[l, 0]:480 / 2 + 160  + r[l, 0], 640 / 2 - 160 + r[m, 1]:640 / 2 + 160  + r[m, 1]],(227,227))
# if I plot the images here both are fine. 
# Now replacing the planes one by one. 
imgR[:,:,0] = imgDNew
imgR[:,:,1] = imgNew[:,:,1]
imgR[:,:,2] = imgNew[:,:,2]

imgG[:,:,1] = imgDNew
imgG[:,:,2] = imgNew[:,:,2]
imgG[:,:,0] = imgNew[:,:,0]

imgB = imgNew
imgB[:,:,2] = imgDNew
imgB[:,:,0] = imgNew[:,:,0]
imgB[:,:,1] = imgNew[:,:,1]

 #Now if I plot the images my original image is changed (imgNew) and imgR,imgG,imgB images are wrong.
```

I don't understand what's wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have this statement: `imgB = imgNew` which essentially makes `imgB` to be the same image as `imgNew`. So when you manipulate `imgB` in following lines it also changes `imgNew`. If you wanted `imgB` to be a copy of `imgNew` you have to explicitly use a copy function.

Comment: what's that copy function?

Comment: `imgNew.copy()`

Comment: The following link explains the issue you are having. 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5234279/947212