# Why I can only change a list in a for loop when I use brackets?

Tags: python, list, iteration

When I use brackets to `item` in the second example, the list can be changed.

```
list1 = [[1, 2]]

for item in list1:
    item = [88, 88]

print(list1)

-----------------

list2 = [[[1, 2]]]

for item in list2:
    item[0] = [88, 88]

print(list2)
```

output:

```
[[1, 2]]   
[[[88, 88]]]
```

I did a search to find that `item` is just a temporary name for the element. Not the item itself.
So why when adding `[]` to "item" the list itself can be changed?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I'm not expecting anything, I'm just wondering why this happens.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python list doesn't reflect variable change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080552/python-list-doesnt-reflect-variable-change)

Comment: Also check this, different situation but same reason https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234126/python-variable-scope-passing-by-reference-or-copy

Comment: `item[0]` is syntactic sugar for a (mutating) method call: `item[0] = [88,88]` is equivalent to `item.__setitem__(0, [88, 88])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think you should read about [Iteration in python](https://towardsdatascience.com/python-basics-iteration-and-looping-6ca63b30835c).

Just to clear things up:

- `list1 = [[1, 2]]` means you have `list1` containing a list, which contains the list `[1,2]` at `list1[0]`.
- `list2 = [[[1, 2]]]` means you have `list2` containing the list `[[1, 2]]`.

Secondly, in order to change the value of the first item in the list, from `[1,2]` to `[88,88]`, you can write:

```
list1 = [[1, 2]]

for item in list1:
    item[0] = 88
    item[1] = 88

print(list1)
```

output:

```
[[88, 88]]
```

**Now, let's explain:**

For each iteration of the for loop the variable `item` is assigned with just a copy of the value of an item in the list, so changes made to `item` won't be reflected in the list.

That is why in your first attempt, (with `list1`) when you iterated over the list - `item = [88, 88]` only changed the copy and not the actual list (the copy here was of the list `[1,2]`).

In your second attempt, i.e:

```
for item in list2:
    item[0] = [88, 88]
```

For each iteration of the for loop, you are accessing `item[0]` which is a copy of the **reference** to the first element in `item`. Therefore when you assign value to it, the value is changed in the list.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, In the first example, when your program goes through the for loop, it gets the value of item (being [1, 2]), inside the for loop you change the variable item to [88, 88], not actually updating the list itself, but rather updating the variable containing [1, 2].

In the second example, the for loop returns the variable item as the second list inside list2. When you use the square brackets it gets the index of 0 in that list, meaning it looks for the 0th element in the list and then updates that to your value of [88, 88].

Hope this helps.